# vertical align span on window resize go to another line

Tags: html, css

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hqu6t0en/) is here.

I have spans inside div which will split into 3 vertically align row. It works normally in high resolution browser but when I resize browser it colaps. You can resize jsfiddle window and u'll see what am I saying.

How can I solve that?

```
<div class="postPrevContent cal">
                <span>იანვარი</span>
                <span>თებერვალი</span>
                <span>მარტი</span>
                <span>აპრილი</span>
                <span>მაისი</span>
                <span>ივნისი</span>
                <span>ივლისი</span>
                <span>აგვისტო</span>
                <span>სექტემბერი</span>
                <span>ოქტომბერი</span>
                <span>ნოემბერი</span>
                <span>დეკემბერი</span>

            </div>
```

Comment: mine doesnt collapse, running FF41. What browser are you on?

Comment: mine doesn't collapse either

Comment: resize result window into 300 px and you'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a
    min-width:100px
in your .cal span css class

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries in your CSS, this will make it into 2 columns instead of 3 when the page is below a 500px wide:

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .cal span {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hqu6t0en/1/

you can then so the same again for a wide of 250px and make width 100% to make one column when even smaller. Or apply a minimum width to .col to stop it getting below 250px but keep 2 columns

```
@media (max-width: 250px){
    .cal span {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Or

```
.cal {
    margin: 10px 0;
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change span to div, style float left and width in percent (of corse in *.css and class is beather), set min-width of parent div. 150 if you think text is max 50px width.

```
<div style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 800px;">
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">AAAAAAAA</div>
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">BBBBBBBB</div>
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">CCCCCCCCC</div>
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">AAAAAAAAAA</div>      
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">BBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
        <div style=" width: 33%;float: left;">CCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
        </div>
```

PS. Set max-width for big display. Set centre text in div.